# cant retrieve items from sharepoint list

Tags: sharepoint, typescript

I am able see items in browser If I use it in browser. I use same url within service below, and there is no response, if I change url with some global api url for exp: "https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?type=artist&q=" it works as I expected. so actually service works also.

It means my problem about sharepoint list api, it requires some specific parameters, but cant figure it out what I did in browser but did not in http request in that service.

api.service:

```
import {Http} from '@angular/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import {Injectable}  from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class dService {
    constructor(private http_: Http){}
    getAnnouncements(urllapi){
        return this.http_.get(urllapi).map(res=>res.json());
    }
}
```

-

```
//this.someService.getAnnouncements("https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?type=artist&q=") it works as I expected 
this.someService.getAnnouncements("http://milespoint1:33333/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Announcement5Jan')/items").subscribe((res) => {
             debugger
             this.tweetsdata = res.json().data.statuses;
      this.isLoading=false;
             console.log("spotify service data:"+res)});
```

browser:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you don't request for strictly `JSON` data SharePoint REST API will give you XML data (same data as your browser) thus making your

```
this.tweetsdata = res.json()
```

line to fail. Try changing your service constructor and method to

```
import {Http, Response, Headers} from '@angular/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import {Injectable}  from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class dService {
    private headers: Headers;

    constructor(private http_: Http){
          this.headers = new Headers();
          this.headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
          this.headers.append('Accept', 'application/json;odata=verbose');
    }

    getAnnouncements(urllapi){
        return this.http_.get(urllapi, {headers: this.headers}).map(res=>res.json());
    }
}
```

Let me know if that helps.